# Displaying certain items from a textfile

Tags: visual-studio-2010, listbox, text-files

So I have a form with a menu bar and a lstbox. On the menu bar is the Display option with 3 choices; all, fiction, or nonfiction. The textfile has book titles, author, category (fic or nonfic), stock, price, in that order. When the user clicks on Display all, I want all the titles to display in the listbox. If they click on Nonfic, just the nonfic titles, and same with fiction. This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub menuDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles menuDisplay.Click

    Dim books() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Books.txt")
    Dim data() As String
    Dim allBooksTitle, allNonFicTitle, allFicTitle As String

    For i As Integer = 0 To books.Count - 1
        data = books(i).Split(","c)
        allBooksTitle = data(2)
        If data(2).Trim = "N" Then
            allNonFicTitle = data(0)
        ElseIf data(2).Trim = "F" Then
            allFicTitle = data(0)
        End If
    Next

    ' show result
    If menuDisplayAll.Checked Then
        lstBox.Items.Add(allBooksTitle)
    ElseIf menuDisplayFic.Checked Then
        lstBox.Items.Add(allFicTitle)
    ElseIf menuDisplayNonFic.Checked Then
        lstBox.Items.Add(allNonFicTitle)
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not quite sure how to write a code for just either the fiction or nonfiction book titles to display and for the listbox to refresh between each button instead of adding to the list box. Any help is greatly apppreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The best way of displaying the data in this code is to move the display code into the processing loop.

```
Private Sub menuDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles menuDisplay.Click

    Dim books() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Books.txt")

    lstbox.Items.Clear() 'remove all items from the listbox

    For i As Integer = 0 To books.Count - 1
        Dim data() As String 'Moved inside to limit scope
        Dim allBooksTitle, allNonFicTitle As String

        data = books(i).Split(","c)
        allBooksTitle = data(2) 'store the two fields
        allNonFicTitle = data(0)

        If menuDisplayAll.Checked Then 'check for each item
            lstBox.Items.Add(allBooksTitle)
        ElseIf menuDisplayFic.Checked AndAlso data(2).Trim = "F" Then
            lstBox.Items.Add(allNonFicTitle) 
        ElseIf menuDisplayNonFic.Checked AndAlso data(2).Trim = "N"Then
            lstBox.Items.Add(allNonFicTitle)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

However if you use .net 3.5 or later it could be cleaner to use LINQ

```
Private Sub menuDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles menuDisplay.Click

    Dim books() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Books.txt")

    lstbox.Items.Clear()
    Dim query As IEnumerable(Of String)
    If menuDisplayAll.Checked Then 'check for each item 
            query = From book As String In books let data As String() = book.Split(',') Select data(0)
    ElseIf menuDisplayFic.Checked
            query = From book As String In books let data As String() = book.Split(',')  Where data(2).Trim = "F" Select data(2)
    ElseIf menuDisplayNonFic.Checked
            query = From book As String In books let data As String() = book.Split(',')  Where data(2).Trim = "N" Select data(2)
    End If

    lstBox.Items.AddRange(query)
End Sub
```